# Como puedo utilizar destructuring con un bucle for

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo convertir una función que tiene cómo parámetro un arreglo de objetos para que me valide un con un bucle for, pero con el método **destructuring**.

Yo realizé el bucle `for`, pero no sé aplicarlo con *destructuring*

```
Const estudiantes = [{
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Boby",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 17,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
      conducta: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Eliezer",
      apellido: "Gil",
      nota: 16,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
      conducta: false
...
//Validacion de aprobado

const validacion = (estudiantes) => {

  for (const alumno of estudiantes) {
    if (alumno.conducta && alumno.nota >= 10) {
      console.log(alumno.nombre + " " + alumno.apellido + " - Aprobado")
    } else {
      console.log(alumno.nombre + " " + alumno.apellido + " - No Aprobado")
    }
  }
}
validacion(estudiantes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#desestructuraci%C3%B3n_de_objetos), necesitas definir una variable (o constante) por cada propiedad del objeto, entre llaves:

```js
let estudiantes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Boby",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 17,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
      conducta: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Eliezer",
      apellido: "Gil",
      nota: 16,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",  
      conducta: false
    }
];

 //Validacion de aprobado

const validacion = (estudiantes) => {
    for(const alumno of estudiantes) {
        // Desestructurar
        let {id, nombre, apellido, nota, curso, conducta} = alumno;
        // Ya puedes acceder a las variables directamente
        if (conducta && nota >= 10){
            console.log(nombre+" "+apellido+" - Aprobado");
        } else {
           console.log(nombre+" "+apellido+" - No Aprobado");
        }
    }
}
validacion(estudiantes);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no tenia claro si podia usar variables dentro del bucle